# .Net CultureInfo Month Names returning an extra empty string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, xamarin, cultureinfo

I have the following code to get a list of Month names:

```
var monthNames = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
```

For some reason, this keeps returning an additional empty string value along with the Month names:

[image]

I am using Xamarin Studio. Anyone else encounter this before?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some calendars like [`TaiwanLunisolarCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.taiwanlunisolarcalendar?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) or [`KoreanLunisolarCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.koreanlunisolarcalendar?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) have 13 months.

In a 12-month calendar, the 13th element of the array is an empty string.

> [DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_DateTimeFormatInfo_MonthNames)
>   A one-dimensional array of type String containing the culture-specific
>   full names of the months. In a 12-month calendar, the 13th element of
>   the array is an empty string. The array for `InvariantInfo` contains
>   `"January"`, `"February"`, `"March"`, `"April"`, `"May"`, `"June"`, `"July"`,
>   `"August"`, `"September"`, `"October"`, `"November"`, `"December"`, and `""`.

Comment: Ah! I should have done more research before posting. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I was curious why that decision was made; turns out there are lunisolar calendars which do infact have 13 months. [Taiwan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.taiwanlunisolarcalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) - [Korea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.koreanlunisolarcalendar(v=vs.110).aspx), etc

Comment: @Rob Thank you for mentioning that calendars, I added them to the answer as examples of calendars with 13 monthes.